# How to present a view full-screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, view, uikit, swiftui

I worked to a login `view`, now I want to present the `view` after login, but I do not want the user to have the possibility to return to the login `view`. In `UIkit` I used `present()`, but it seems in `SwiftUI` `presentation(_ modal: Modal?)` the `view` does not take the entire screen. `Navigation` also isn't an option.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that Apple deleted function presentation(....)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I do not want the user to have the possibility to return to the login view

In that case you shouldn't be presenting away from the login view but replacing it entirely.

You could do this by conditionally building the login view or the "app view".

Something like this...

```
// create the full screen login view
struct LoginView: View {
    // ...
}

//create the full screen app veiw
struct AppView: View {
    // ...
}

// create the view that swaps between them
struct StartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var isLoggedIn: Bool // you might not want to use this specifically.

    var body: some View {
        isLoggedIn ? AppView() : LoginView()
    }
}
```

By using a pattern like this you are not presenting or navigating away from the login view but you are replacing it entirely so it is no longer in the view hierarchy at all.

This makes sure that the user cannot navigate back to the login screen.

Equally... by using an `@EnvironmentObject` like this you can edit it later (to sign out) and your app will automatically be taken back to the login screen.

Comment: That sounds great, but I have one more question: In the LoginView's model I get some data from the server which I need in AppView, How could I transfer those data to the AppView?

Comment: @SorinLica that is what the EnvironmentObject stuff is for. I'll admit that I don't really know fully how to use the EnvironmentObject stuff yet but that's what it's there for. For instance you might want to hold your user information in there for instance. Then anything that uses the EnvironmentObject can access that information and the views will be updated when it is changed. Check out this talk ... https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/226

Comment: Does this even compile given that some View cannot be resolved to a type?

Comment: yeay, since when can you return one of two different types ... this will error

Comment: I've got "Cannot convert return expression of type 'AppView' to return type 'some View'" message from complier.

Comment: For your followup question, a common pattern for login information might be to have a singleton "UserViewModel" which is an ObservableObject with \@Published attributes and a "shared" static member which holds the singleton. Then any view that needs it can add the \@ObservedObject member and react to any changes. But this should really be in a separate SO question.

Answer (score 5):

Encapsulate the body in a Group to eliminate compiler errors:

```
struct StartView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth

var body: some View {
    Group {
        if userAuth.isLoggedin {
            AppView()
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth 
    var body: some View {
        if !userAuth.isLoggedin {
            return AnyView(LoginView())
        } else {
            return AnyView(HomeView())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Posting an answer is nice, but explaining how it solves the question is better.

Comment: Please don’t use `AnyView` like this, it’s an anti-pattern. Since a `View`’s content is by default a ViewBuilder you don’t need to specify the `return` statements or use `AnyView()`.

Answer (score 0):

I made this extension for myself. Any feedback/ideas are welcome. :)

https://github.com/klemenkosir/SwiftUI-FullModal

#### Usage

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.isPresented.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Present")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Some title")
        }
        .present($isPresented, view: ModalView(isPresented: $isPresented))
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isPresented.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea how to trigger onAppear at ContentView after dismissed from ModalView?

Comment: Hmm thats a tough one. Not sure if its possible right now. You could just modify the `.present` method to have an optional dismissed callback that gets called everytime the presented screen is dismissed.

Comment: I've tried using .transition(.move) it works it can trigger event such as onAppear between Views but it also seems has a issue with NavigationView visibility.