# How can I launch a SwiftUI View without Navigation back tracking?

Tags: swiftui

I want to launch a View as a standalone View without the navigation hierarchy. The reason that I don't want to use a NavigationButton is that I don't want the user to return to the calling form.

I have tried the following approach that is similar to how the first view is launched in ScenceDelegate but nothing happens:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let window = appDelegate.getNewWindow()
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: NewView())
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I have a legitimate reason not to use the navigation UI, I'm leaving the explanation out to keep this short. I'm avoiding Storyboards to keep this as a simple as possible.

Thank you for any solution suggestions.

Comment: Is this for a login screen by any chance? Or something along those lines?

Comment: If you only don't want to go to the navigation route because you do not want to the user to be able to go back, you can just disable the navigationbar's back button, or even completely hide the navigationbar.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, its for a login screen. I just figured out that this is working in the Simulator, but not in the Canvas and that makes perfect sense! I'm going to leave the question open for a little while to see if anyone has a better way.

Comment: In that case... you shouldn’t be transitioning away like this. You should really be replacing the entire screen with a new one. Using an EnvironmentObject like `userLoggedIn` and update the view to show the login screen or your app screen depending on that state.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557979/how-to-present-a-view-full-screen-in-swiftui/56558160?noredirect=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to present a view full-screen in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557979/how-to-present-a-view-full-screen-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I accomplished loading a new root View.

I added the following to the AppDelegate code

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
     var window: UIWindow?

   ...

    func loadNewRootSwiftUIView(rootViewController: UIViewController)
    {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

And placed the following in my form:

```
struct LaunchView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(
                action: {
                   LaunchLoginView()
            },
                label: {
                    Text("Login")
            }
            )
        }
    }
}

func LaunchLoginView(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let vContoller = UIHostingController(rootView: LoginView())
    appDelegate.loadNewRootSwiftUIView(rootViewController: vContoller)
}
```

Comment: I have tried this with SwiftUI Beta 5. It compiles but nothing happens, i.e. no new Window. Does this approach still work in Beta 5? Do I need to hook it into the SceneDelegate somehow?

Comment: I'm using SwiftUI Beta 7 and having the same issue. Nothing happens. Does anybody know how to deal with this situation?

Comment: That's really making use of the transitional state of SwiftUI; App Delegates and RootViewControllers will eventually be removed completely. And, near as I can tell, Apple isn't really looking at ways of doing full-view replacement style navigation (a la, replacing the root view controller) in SwiftUI. And that sucks! Conditionally showing welcome screens and login screens or going direct to a main Home Screen shouldn't require "single-page app" thinking, as suggested above by Fogmeister (which is the only workaround currently). :(