# How to go Home Screen from Login screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I want to go Home Screen from login Screen without using NavigationView. So that the home screen doesn't show the back bar button.

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557979/how-to-present-a-view-full-screen-in-swiftui

Comment: @RuchiMakadia Thanks, But it's not working for me

Comment: maybe try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447320/5981293 or the question in general? Please provide more code to make an example!